# Android Capture Picture with CameraCaptureSession Rotating the picture to landscape

Tags: java, android, mobile

On some devices the picture taking by CaptureSession is rotating to landscape thats ok.

My problem is that I will detect if the picture is saved in landscape and rotate it back and save it. Because now as result the user got the profile image rotated for some models.

For now I have tried many solutions including

```
getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
```

Which always return 0.

I was thinking if the Exif tag in the JPEG file was not set for some reason, but I have not find anything about it.

My solution that works best so far is this one. Which just check height and width. This don't work always. Lots of devices have problem with rotated pictures.

```
public static Bitmap rotate90ifneeded(Bitmap bitmap, int width, int height) {
    Bitmap bitmap2 = bitmap;
    if(bitmap.getHeight() < bitmap.getWidth()) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(90);
        bitmap2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap , 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }
    return bitmap2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to determine image rotation.

```
public int getCameraPhotoOrientation(Uri imageUri, String imagePath) {
        int rotate = 0;
        try {
            _context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(imageUri, null);
            File imageFile = new File(imagePath);
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(
                    imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                    ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

            switch (orientation) {
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    rotate = 270;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    rotate = 180;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    rotate = 90;
                    break;
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return rotate;
    }
```

And if the method wouldn't return Zero rotate the image.

```
int degree=getCameraPhotoOrientation(Uri.fromFile(tempFile), fPath);
if (degree!= 0) {
      bitmap = tools.rotateOrientationCall(bitmap, degree);
 }
```

Rotate your bitmap.

```
public Bitmap rotateOrientationCall(Bitmap src, float degree) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(degree);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(src, 0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }
```

Comment: What should i do if degree is 0.? should i combine mine rotate90ifneeded if degree is 0.

Comment: Use the same file without rotating if it's zero.

Comment: There is a android bugg i think in 5.0+ that makes it always return 0. Can't find any fix for that.